# How to build all projects after pushing changes

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration

In my attempt to implement CI for my projects in Jenkins I came upon this issue that is most likely related to the way I organize these projects. This can be reduced to the following:

- I have 2 solutions: `LegacyApp.sln` and `ModernApp.sln`
- These solutions both contain a set of projects that are often modified. These are the *shared projects*.
- The `LegacyApp` solution also contains the legacy console app project. This is not developed anymore.
- The `ModernApp` solution also contains the GUI app project (say WPF). This is under development and it is being changed often, together with the shared projects.

(*Note: in real life there are about 20 shared projects and each solution contains 10-15 unique projects*)

I use `ModernApp.sln` to make the changes I need. Sometimes these changes are breaking for `LegacyApp.sln`, but I am not aware of it until the nightly build fails (because only the nightly build handles `LegacyApp.sln`).

Question is: **what is the best way to handle this so that the CI build fails as soon as I push the changes?**

Obviously, I have to include the LegacyApp projects in the CI build, but how? The options I can think of are not perfect:

1. Keep using the 2 solutions and configure the CI build to build them sequentially. This does not scale when I add a new shared project, as I have to update both solutions.
2. Combine the 2 solutions into one called `AllApps.sln` that includes the shared projects, the unique projects from `LegacyApp` and the unique projects from `ModernApp`. The downside is the legacy app projects are loaded in the IDE all the time (as opposed to using `ModernApp.sln` in which they were not included).
3. Keep using the 2 solutions, but have the build 'merge' them at build time on the build server so that it automatically creates the above `AllApps.sln`  (or something equivalent) as a temporary file to be used by the CI build. I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to store/maintain some kind of dependency configuration so that only the dependent projects will get built each time you merge code.